# Domino incorrect Return Receipt Tracking Case

Tags: ibm-domino

Domino incorrect Return Receipt Tracking Case

User 'A' (AUTHOR) sent an email to other local user named B,C,D in TO/CC. User 'A' (AUTIHOR) have received RETURN RECEIPT from another user F who was NOT in TO/CC list.

How can I track that why user A (AUTHOR) received RETURN RECEIPT from the user 'F' who was not in the To/CC list?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely reason for the return-receipt from user "F" is that there's either forwarding to their email, or there's a mail rule in someone's mail file sending mail to user "F"

You should search the mail routing log events to see what happened. If you have message tracking enabled, you could use that to track the message flow.

Comment: Ok Case Solved.
Using the few days older backup files (we have a month archival policy that takes daily backup n keep for 30 days) , and inspecting activity trend of who accesses the DB files, it got revealed that the user F did opened the other user mail files that triggered the receipt. Disciplinary actions have been taken against him. Thank you for the pointers and support.